# React Native FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. I need someone to look at this?

Tags: react-native

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\Nelson Ndimba\Documents\MTN-YelloHive\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Nelson Ndimba.gradle\caches\7.1.1\scripts\4gzdkdviqbv5h262ml6gwf2d7).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problems come from your Java version.
did you install JDK11 as mentioned in the CLI project set up ?
if yes and the problem is always there then make sure to add a variable envirenement to your system named JAVA_HOME with value :
"C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot"

Note 1: make sure to restart you PC after this.

Note 2: the path may change based on the jdk 11 subversion and where your system stores installed software